# Товары из дерева категорий Django-mptt

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, mptt

Подскажите как вывести товары категории используя модель Django-Mptt
При вызове category.product_set.all() получаю ошибку AttributeError at /category/cross/
'Category' object has no attribute 'product_set'.

models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категории'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Имя категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail',kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

```
class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'
        order_with_respect_to='slug'

    category =  TreeForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, related_name='category', verbose_name="Выберите категорию",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Наименоватние продукта')
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Главное изображение',upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    ***features*** = models.ManyToManyField("specs.ProductFeatures", blank=True, related_name='features_for_product')
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание товара',null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Цена')
```

views.py

```
class CategoryDetailView(CartMixin, DetailView):

    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        category = self.get_object()
        context['cart'] = self.cart
        context['categories'] = self.model.objects.all()
        if not query and not self.request.GET:
            context['category_products'] = category.product_set.all()
            return context
        if query:
            products = category.product_set.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
            context['category_products'] = products
            return context
```